# zsh and bashrc command not found ts-node

Tags: bash, macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I'm having an issue with macOS, it's a company laptop that has already been set up when I got it.

- It had zsh.
- I was working on a project with Java, and the path to Java was not working, each time I launched a new terminal I had to set it up.
- I thought that the problem would be easier to handle with bash so I tried uninstalling it
- Zsh is still here, but now I can't use ts-node nore nodemon to run my code (but if I try to run it whith a script in my package.json it will run).
- I managed to switch to bash by default, but ts-node is still not available.
- I tried uninstalling and reinstalling ts-node npm and node.

Any idea on how to fix this mess whithout formatting the computer?

Comment: can you `echo $PATH` and see if you have something like `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node/bin`?

Comment: If it's a company laptop, it might be faster to contact your company's IT department or talk with one of your colleagues about this. I'm sure you're not the only one who's had this problem in your company. :)

Comment: @Paul_M : I would first have a look whether or not `ts-node` is still present. If it is, just fix your PATH so that it can be found. If it isn't, I would go with MarlonRichert's idea to ask your IT for installation. Or you install it by yourself and post here details of the installation, including error messages, and how you verified that installation did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was that PATH didn't include node_modules.

Thank you @deepakchethan.

I corrected it but had some issues since editing the `~/.bashrc` file did not save the path and using terminal with `export PATH=$PATH:/Users/<user>/.npm_global/bin` didn't work either.

I had to add the path by editing `/etc/bashrc`.